# Convert C++ Header Files To Python

Tags: c++, python, data-structures, enums, header

I have a C++ header that contains #define statements, Enums and Structures.  I have tried using the h2py.py script that is included with Python to no avail (except giving me the #defines converted).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know h2py, but you may want to look at 'ctypes' and 'ctypeslib'.  ctypes is included with python 2.5+, and is targeted at creating binary compatibility with c-structs.

If you add ctypeslib, you get a sub-tool called codegen, which has a 'h2xml.py' script, and a 'xml2py.py', the combination of which will auto-generate the python code you're looking for from C++ headers.

ctypeslib:http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ctypeslib/0.5.4a

h2xml.py will require another tool called gccxml: http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html

it's best to check out (via CVS) the latest version of gccxml and build it yourself (actually easier done than said).  The pre-packaged version is old.

Comment: I went down this rabbit hole to try to get gccxml using CVS.  It was nearly impossible on Windows.  Here is a better way about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840268/where-to-get-compiled-version-of-gccxml-on-windows .  Or here is a directly link to the project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctypes/files/gccxml/

Comment: Here is a really good starting point for generating python code from a .h file: http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/

Answer (score 2):

Just found [pycparser](https://pypi.org/project/pycparser/). May be useful.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, h2py.py isn't intended to convert anything other than #define macros.  I did run across [cppheaderparser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppheaderparser/), which might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the idea that h2py had anything to do with structs or enums?

From the source

```
# Read #define's and translate to Python code.
# Handle #include statements.
# Handle #define macros with one argument.
```

The words 'enum' and 'struct' never appear in the module.