# Where to get compiled version of gccxml on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

Can anyone point to a place where I can get a compiled version of gccxml on windows?

Answer (score 2):

Later versions can be found here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygccxml/files/gccxml-setup/

Answer (score 1):

ctypes sourceforge project also has a [gccxml binary for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctypes/files/gccxml/2008-08-12/).

Answer (score 0):

From the gccxml [download page](http://www.gccxml.org/files/v0.6/).

Comment: This version is 0.6 as of Sept 2012, the other two links above are at 0.9.