# porting CPP defines to python

Tags: c++, python, c

I have a program (written in C/C++) that behaves as a socket server. I'd like to write the client in python. The packets exchanged over the TCP socket follow a "home-made" protocol (simple) using macros defined as #define... in a XXX.h file.
I'd like to parse the XXX.h file to generate a equivalent XXX.py
The XXX.h file only contains CPP macro definitions (and comments) e.g:

```
//the following commands are used when talking to the server
//A tcp message is: the command(32bit word) followed by the flags (32 bits)
#define CMD_DO_SOMETHING1  1  //this does something
#define CMD_DO_SOMETHING2  2  //that does something else
 #define FLAG1   0x0001        //These flags are used as parameter in cmd2
 #define FLAG2   0x0002
 #define FLAG3   0x0004
 #define FLAG4   0x0008
 #define TEST_FLAG1(x) (x&FLAG1) //this tests for flag1
```

I would like to get something like: XXX.py:

```
CMD_DO_SOMETHING1=1
CMD_DO_SOMETHING2=2
 FLAG1=1
 ...
 def test_flag1(x):
    return(x&flag1)
```

I have been briefly looking at swig, but was not convinced it really did what I am looking for. Parsing the XXX.h file manually and matching regular expression feels wrong. So does the idea of running CPP on my *.py file.
At least, the constant definition should be converted so I don't have to rewrite them twice.
Any better ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert C++ Header Files To Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374217/convert-c-header-files-to-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`h2py.py` does exactly that. It is included in the Python distribution(*) in Tools/scripts

If you need to convert more than #defines, see the question [Convert C++ Header Files To Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/374217/222914)

EDIT: (*) It is included at least in the full source distribution.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot find h2py on my machine (Fedora FC16). YUM does not give me any hint on where to get it from. I nevertheless found the source (copy/paste it) and it does what I want. If you know how I should get h2py more "cleanly" let me know. and thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user1159290 There is a separate package, python-tools I think, for Fedora. But you don't need more than the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you use the macro pre-processor to do this? This is what they are for.